# Default relay bandwidth?

Tags: relays, bandwidth

I successfully setup my Tor relay last night, and it has been running for a few hours now. But looking at it this morning, it is not getting that much advertised bandwidth. It has gone up since the first few hours last night, but not by much. Is this due to not much usage through my relay?

Also, I noticed that my "RelayBandwidthRate/Burst" are still commented out because I guess I missed that last night during my initial setup. Does this mean that I am giving off unlimited bandwidth, or is it capped at the 100 KB for the BandwidthRate and 200 KB for the BandwidthBurst even though they are still commented out.

My relay works just fine, the log isn't throwing any errors, it's just the bandwidth that is a little low. Sorry for the noob questions, and thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Now my bandwidth is just nonexistent. It was still a bit on the low side, and then it just did a sharp hard drop.

Answer (score 2):

https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay

The tl;dr of the link above is that it can take 2 months to ramp up to full utilization.

Note also that the more bandwidth you are providing, the more "attractive" you are to traffic.  A 20KB/sec relay may meet the minimum standard for a relay, but won't actually contribute to the network.

And, yes, if you haven't specified a bandwidth cap, your relay will use all the bandwidth it can (eventually).